# Resampling not producing expected result of principal component analysis

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying following code to produce confidence intervals of principal component analysis using resampling with replacement (like bootstrap). I am using first 4 columns of iris dataset:

The prcomp function produces following output:

```
> mydf = iris[1:4]
> print(prcomp(mydf))
Standard deviations:
[1] 2.0562689 0.4926162 0.2796596 0.1543862

Rotation:
                     PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
Sepal.Width  -0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
Petal.Length  0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
Petal.Width   0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574
```

Using resampling with replacement:

```
> times = 1000
> ll = list()
> for(i in 1:times) {
+ tempdf =  mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), replace = TRUE), ]
+ ll[[length(ll)+1]] = prcomp(tempdf)$rotation
+ }
> 
> dd = data.frame(apply(simplify2array(ll), 1:2, mean))
> print(dd)
                      PC1          PC2          PC3          PC4
Sepal.Length  0.005574165 -0.039480258  0.044537991  0.007778055
Sepal.Width  -0.002587333 -0.040273812 -0.050793200 -0.005473271
Petal.Length  0.015681233  0.010952361 -0.005769051 -0.011351172
Petal.Width   0.006513656  0.008296928 -0.041805210  0.019109323
```

Determining lower confidence interval:

```
> ddlower = data.frame(apply(simplify2array(ll), 1:2, quantile, probs=0.025))
> print(ddlower)
                    PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length -0.3859257 -0.7274809 -0.6560139 -0.3807826
Sepal.Width  -0.1127749 -0.7907801 -0.6818251 -0.3941001
Petal.Length -0.8633386 -0.2058064 -0.1333520 -0.4919584
Petal.Width  -0.3702979 -0.1328146 -0.6203322 -0.8088710
```

Determining upper confidence interval:

```
> ddupper = data.frame(apply(simplify2array(ll), 1:2, quantile, probs=0.975))
> print(ddupper)
                   PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4
Sepal.Length 0.3860431 0.7250412 0.6632126 0.3831889
Sepal.Width  0.1111863 0.7993649 0.6758156 0.3987939
Petal.Length 0.8638549 0.2106540 0.1318556 0.4915670
Petal.Width  0.3721362 0.1510708 0.6246988 0.8083421
```

I find that the loading values are very different. Moreover, the confidence intervals are around 0 for all the variables and components. I checked with other (large) datasets also and the findings are very similar. From these confidence intervals none of the loadings are significantly different from 0. There is obviously some error in the code but I cannot seem to find it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, didn't you fail to extract the first column only of the `$rotation` in the line `"+  ll[[length(ll)+1]] = prcomp(tempdf)$rotation"` ? (Think that the mean of the 1000 first princomps should be very similar to the original computation of the prcomp_rotation )

Comment: The OP is capturing the *entire* matrix of eignevectors (loadings) for the variables in each of 1000 bootstrap resamples. The later commands are then computing the percentile confidence intervals for individual elements of each eigenvector.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms : This was in my question. The mean was close to 0 due to the sign problem described in the answer by Gavin Simpson.

Comment: @rnso: ah, I see. Now this seems cleared. Happily my own routine (in my small "pocket"-matrix calculator MatMate) seems to work well giving normalized signs by implementation... (I reproduce the R: `prcomp` -procedure (according to its manual) by a svd-rotation on the covariance-matrix and had implemented that sign normalizing for the procedure `gettrans(cov,"pca")` apparently sufficiently for this actual case

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm not familiar with R so far. Then it should be sufficient to normalize the sign of the eigenvectors (for instance to be nonnegative for all principal components of the item `sepal.length` ) in each experiment of the 1000 samples (this is only text correction of my deleted previous comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the sign of an Eigenvector is not defined (you can flip the configuration and have the same result), it doesn't make sense to form a confidence interval on the the *signed* value of the loading.

**Instead compute the confidence interval on the *absolute* value of the loading, not the signed value.**

Think what happens to your interval when the Eigenvector for say `Sepal.Length` flips from ~ `-0.3` to ~ `+0.3`? The loading is similar in both cases when considered from an absolute size point of view. When you look at the actual signed value however, it would be logical for the loading to be on average 0 as you are averaging a lot of ~-0.3s and ~0.3s.

To visualise why your original attempt failed, run:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- iris[1:4]
times <- 1000
ll <- vector(mode = "list", length = times)
for (i in seq_len(times)) {
  tempdf  <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), replace = TRUE), ]
  ll[[i]] <- prcomp(tempdf)$rotation
}
```

This is effectively your code, modified to suit my sensibilities. Now extract the loading for `Sepal.Length` on `PC1` and draw a histogram of the values:

```
hist(sapply(ll, `[`, 1, 1))
```

which produces

[image]

Instead compute the confidence interval on the *absolute* value of the loading, not the signed value.

For example

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- iris[1:4]
times <- 1000
ll <- vector(mode = "list", length = times)
for (i in seq_len(times)) {
  tempdf  <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), replace = TRUE), ]
  ll[[i]] <- abs(prcomp(tempdf)$rotation) ## NOTE: abs(...)
}
```

This gives:

```
> data.frame(apply(simplify2array(ll), 1:2, quantile, probs = 0.025))
                    PC1         PC2        PC3       PC4
Sepal.Length 0.33066830 0.578558222 0.45955051 0.2252653
Sepal.Width  0.05211013 0.623424084 0.49591685 0.2351746
Petal.Length 0.84823899 0.133137927 0.01226608 0.4607265
Petal.Width  0.34284824 0.007403214 0.44932031 0.6780493

> data.frame(apply(simplify2array(ll), 1:2, quantile, probs = 0.975))
                   PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4
Sepal.Length 0.3891499 0.7443276 0.6690553 0.3898237
Sepal.Width  0.1186205 0.7988607 0.7010495 0.4083784
Petal.Length 0.8653324 0.2153410 0.1450756 0.4933340
Petal.Width  0.3742441 0.1645692 0.6350899 0.8154254
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Only I have to recover the sign of the loadings from original values. Otherwise they are all positive now.

Comment: Why bother? The sign is arbitrary and may well be different when you run the code on a different machine, OS, compiler, CPU etc.

Comment: I need the signs for interpretation of data to know which variables are positively related and which ones are inversely related.

Comment: Sorry @rnso, my comment was a little terse. I meant, report the *observed* eigenvectors but also a confidence interval on the absolute value.

Comment: Is this method the 'bootstrap' method or some other procedures are also needed for bootsrap and I need to use the 'boot' package?

Comment: You have done a **non-parametric bootstrap** and formed the **bootstrap percentile confidence intervals**. I was going to suggest using the boot package for this as it will give you different types (including percentile) confidence intervals and estimate bias etc. To use **boot**, you need to write a wrapper function that takes arguments `data` and `indices`, the latter being the indices of the bootstrap sample, and returns the statistics of interest. I'll see about adding an example to my answer; the one bit I'm not sure about is how it handles bootstrapping an entire matrix of values.

Comment: Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044922/confidence-intervals-of-loadings-in-principal-components-in-r

Comment: To answer your question there, "bootstrapping" is "sampling with replacement", at least the **non-parametric** bootstrap is (which is what the answerer at the other Q&A did using **boot**).

Comment: Will this method give same results as boot package? If not, which method is better? Is there a good web link that clarifies this?

Comment: This should (up to variation in the random seed) give the same results for the non-parametric bootstrap and the percentile confidence intervals. The **boot** package is more comprehensive, and provides better confidence interval types (e.g. bias corrected accelerated intervals (via `boot.ci()`). However, and as the Answer at the other question showed, I haven't found a way to do the entire bootstrap and confidence interval thing on all eigenvectors at once. So you'll need to do this at least one principal component at a time, whereas here you do them all at once, but you only get percentile CI

Comment: And as I said, this sampling with replacement is **exactly** what `boot()` is doing by default. Note you really need to run more bootstrap samples to get good coverages in the intervals.

Comment: Getting the lower & upper bounds for the `sepal.length` item as $0.33$ and $0.38$ indicates to use standard-deviation of the 1000 results of that loadings. Isn't the standard-error of the mean more of interest here when the question is the significane of this loading?

Comment: Instead of taking the absolute value of ***each eigenvector-component*** it suffices to re-determine the eigenvectors by changing of the signs *of the  eigenvector as a whole*, for instance to make sure that always the loading of item 1 is positive. (For instance:  if loading of item 1 is in one experiment negative switch the signs ***of all loadings*** in this eigenvector to preserve the correlative relations between the items)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Is that sufficient when you are working with resamples from the data? I can imagine small values flipping signs essentially randomly because they are either not important in the data as a whole or not important for a particular direction of feature space.

Comment: @Gavin: principally it should be realistic that at some item the PC-loadings vary by a small value around zero - with a meaningful mean very near zero. How one can make sure, that the eigenvector as a whole points into the correct direction - to take the (absolutely) highest loading as marker seems to be a strong argument. But if the pc-solution in strongly ambiguous (many nearly uncorrelated items, pc-eigenvalue very near 1) then this might not really suffice. Perhaps the final criterion for the decision whether to flip the direction must be dependent on something else, no final answer yet...